# Stirling Numbers of First Kind Proof by Induction

Tags: combinatorics, induction

Prove the following by using a proof by industion:

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} |s(n,k)| = n!$$

where $s(n,k)$ is the Stirling Numbers of the First Kind.

Workings:

Proof:

The recurrence relation for $s(n,k)$ would be:

$s(n+1,k)=s(n,k-1)-ns(n,k)$

Base case: $n = 0$

So $S(0,0) = 1 = 0!$

Base case holds.

Induction hypothesis:

Suppose that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} |s(n,k)| = n!$ holds for some n.

Then for $n+1$

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n+1} |s(n,k)| = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} |s(n,k)| + |s(n+1,k)|$

= $n! + |s(n+1,k)|$

I'm not sure if what I said so far is correct and what to do next.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a bit mixed up with your indexing.

Suppose that $\sum_{k=0}^n |s(n,k)|=n!$ holds for some n. This is fine.

Then for $n+1$, you need to start with

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} |s(n+1,k)| = \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} |s(n,k-1) - ns(n,k)| = \cdots$$

See if you can take it from there. You want to show that this is equal to $(n+1)!$.

Comment: Right I should use the recurrence relation

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} |s(n+1),k|$

$= \sum \limits_{k=0}^{n+1}s(n,k-1) -\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n+1}ns(n,k)$

From I.H. then 

$\sum \limits_{k=0}^{n+1}s(n,k-1) - nn!$